# Show that Quotient of a C*-algebra is a C*-algebra in its own right

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a commutative C*-algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $J$ be an ideal of $A$ such that $J\in Closed(A)$ and that contains $x^*$ if it contains $x$, for all $x\in A$.

I know that $A/J$ is also a Banach algebra (Rudin FA 11.4) and also has an involution of the form $[x]^*:=[x^*]$ which is well defined (if $[x]=[y]$, $x-y\in J$, so that $x^*-y^* \in J$ and so $[x]^*=[y]^*$).

I would like to prove that $A/J$ is in fact a C*-algebra, that is, that $$||[x][x]^*||=||[x]||^2$$ (the B*-condition is equivalent to the C*-condition).

However I got stuck:

For one direction it is easy:

$$ ||[x][x]^*|| \leq ||[x]||||[x]^*|| = ||[x]||^2 $$ using the fact that $||[x]^*|| \equiv \inf(\{||x^*-j|| | j\in J\}) = \inf(\{||x^*-j^*|| | j\in J\}) = \inf(\{||x-j|| | j\in J\}) \equiv ||[x]||  $ because if $j\in J$ then $j^* \in J$ and $A$ is a C*-algebra, so that $||x-j||=||x^*-j^*||$.

For the other direction, $$ ||[x]||^2 = ||[x]|| ||[x]^*|| \leq ||x-j_1|| ||x^*-j_2|| \stackrel{A\,is\,a\,C*}{=} ||(x-j_1)(x^*-j_2^*)|| = ||x x^*-j_1 x^*-xj_2^*-j_1j_2^* || $$ for all $(j_1,j_2)\in J^2$.

If $\varepsilon>0$, then $\exists j_\varepsilon\in J$ such that $$ ||x x^* -j_\varepsilon||<||x x^*+J||+\varepsilon $$
So now if I could find $(j_1,j_2)\in J^2$ such that $j_\varepsilon=-j_1 x^*-xj_2^*-j_1j_2^*$ then the proof would be complete.

However, I am not sure how to do that, if that is even possible.

Comment: Do you need to restrict to *commutative* algebras?

Comment: Maybe not, but Rudin FA 11.4 applies to commutative algebras, so otherwise one would have to rely on something else.

Comment: The checks you're doing don't rely on commutativity...

Comment: I see, thanks. Still, I am stuck.

Comment: Do you have a little knowledge of approximate units? *(It will be alot easier!)*

Comment: Unfortunately not, and this concept is not mentioned in the book I am reading, so I would prefer a direct as possible proof. In particular I wonder if my approach may be salvaged.

Comment: See when you want to prove that $F(t):=(\sin(t),\cos(t))$  is continuous you can either directly prove it (hard!) or you exploit the characteristic property (easy!). That is the reason why most books follow with quotients only after approximate units. I will give a short intro if you're fine with that?

Comment: That would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approximate Unit**

Regard ball cone:
$$\mathcal{B}_+:=\{A\in\mathcal{A}:\|A\|<1:A\geq0\}$$

Order elements:
$$E,E'\in\mathcal{I}\cap\mathcal{B}_+:\quad E\leq E'$$

Then one has:
$$I\in\mathcal{I}:\quad\|I-IE\|,\|I-EI\|\stackrel{E\to1}{\longrightarrow}0$$

*(That is the hard part!)*

**Quotient Norm**

Note that it holds:
$$1-\sigma(E)\geq0\implies\|1-E\|\leq1$$

An estimate gives:
$$\|A+\mathcal{I}\|\leq\|A-AE\|=\|A(1-E)\|\\
\leq\|A+I\|\cdot1+\|I-IE\|\to\|A+I\|$$

So the norm writes:
$$\|A+\mathcal{I}\|=\lim_{E\to1}\|A-AE\|$$

That gives rise to:
$$\|A+\mathcal{I}\|^2=\lim_{E\to1}\|A-AE\|^2=\lim_{E\to1}\|(1-E)A^*A(1-E)\|\\
\leq1\lim_{E\to1}\|A^*A-A^*AE\|=\|A^*A+\mathcal{I}\|=\|(A+\mathcal{I})^*(A+\mathcal{I})\|$$

Thus it satisfies:
$$\|A+\mathcal{I}\|^2=\|(A+\mathcal{I})^*(A+\mathcal{I})\|$$

Concluding C*-algebra.

Comment: Let me know if you're stuck somewhere.

Comment: Thanks! By $E\leq E'$ you mean $E'-E$ is a positive operator (positive means self-adjoint and with non-negative real spectrum)?

Comment: Yes, exactly!! :)

Comment: And be careful *not* to drop selfadjoint as there are nontrivial nilpotents with positive spectrum.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you order elements in $\mathcal{I}\cap\mathcal{B}_+$, and it seems (from googling "approximate units") that you are trying to say $\mathcal{I}\cap\mathcal{B}_+$ is a net, and then examine the limits of these nets. Is there a reason why you are looking at nets and not just good old sequences? I thought in metric spaces (of which Banach algebras are an example of) sequences are sufficient. All this machinery seems like a huge overkill to prove an inequality.

Comment: @user118719: Yes, exactly: Nets are simple to handle. :) Of course, they admit a sequence but that is needless rather than overkill. ;)

Comment: @user118719: Besides, nets are **EXTREMELY!!!!!!!!!!** powerful: Arbitrary sums, integrals, direct sums, tensor products, direct integrals, etc. etc. etc. *(ONB's for example become a one-liner.)*

Comment: @user118719: For extracting sequence see: [Cauchy Net](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/828762/79762) For order of nets see: [Directed Indices](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/631649/79762) For equivalence see: [Completeness](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/828779/79762)

Comment: Translating this to sequences, you're basically saying there's a sequence in $\mathcal{I}$ intersected with the open unit ball, whose elements are positive, and which basically converges to $1$. But how do you know $1$ is a limit point of this thing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25509/discussion-between-freeze-s-and-user118719).